# What conditions of normality must be met for paired/unpaired t-tests?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, data-analysis

> We assume that $X_i \sim N(μ_1, σ_1^2)$ and $Y_i \sim N(μ_2, σ_2^2)$ [i.e. that they are normal distributions with a finite (or known?) mean and variance] [...]
>
> -- Tamhane & Dunlop, *Statistics and Data Analysis*, Section 8.3.2 Matched Pairs Design, p. 283.

Am I correct in understanding that because my two distributions are not normal (see image below), paired and unpaired t-tests cannot be performed on them, and therefore [I should use](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/225006-how-to-find-t-test-of-two-independent-samples-in-matlab#answer_183727) the [ranksum test](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/ranksum.html) instead to determine statistical significance?

[image]

Is it enough for their difference to be mostly normal, or must the distributions themselves also be normal? Looking at Tamhane & Dunlop's discussion, it appears to me their difference has normal distribution properties only if the distributions themselves are normal, and hence I cannot do a paired t-test with this data.

Am I correct? Please correct any misunderstandings I have. I would also appreciate additional free online resources to read.

Comment: Paired $t$-tests need the differences to be normally distributed and independent, but not the underlying distributions; all you are doing is testing the set of differences.  That does not translate into unpaired $t$-tests, where there is only one difference being tested; you want that to be normally distributed (getting a $t$-distribution after estimating its variance) and that puts constraints on the original distributions

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by implying that paired t-tests have more than difference being tested, or how unpaired t-tests have only one difference being tested. I don't know what constraints the distributions have if one models the difference distribution by a Student t-distribution. Please elaborate in an answer here. (My education in statistics is lacking beyond basic probability and set theory.) Otherwise, thank you for your comment; I suppose I must continue with the Wilcoxon rank sum test, and try to read more as time permits from the textbooks I have available (e.g. Kinney 2015).